# HTML minimalization IActionFilter or IResultFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, orchardcms

I'm trying to minimize HTML using filter which is later cached using Orchard.OutputCache module

```
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter != null && !Orchard.UI.Admin.AdminFilter.IsApplied(filterContext.RequestContext))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter = new TidyHtml(filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Filter, filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Output.Encoding);
        }
    }
```

But I have choice of several events

(IActionFilter) **OnActionExecuting**, **OnActionExecuted**

(IResultFilter) **OnResultExecuting**, **OnResultExecuted**

Does it matter which one I use? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Don't use the one that doesn't work

Comment: Suddenly the one that didn't work started working :-P Guess I missed to clear cache or something.

Comment: I'm surprised that there is any point in doing that in the first place. I would have thought that gzip compression would make this counter-beneficial by stealing CPU cycles for no clear size benefit.

Comment: In my benchmarks it's even better than trying to optimize JS or CSS which are cached on client on first request, while HTML is sent with every request and contains lots of whitespace and other redundancy which can be safely removed. Even with Gzip HTML optimization reduces page size by 5-15% on every request depending on how well written your views are. And since result is cached on server and minification takes just couple ms, there's no performance loss, actually larger pages render a bit faster in client browsers and of course saves bandwidth in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but IActionFilter is 50% faster than IResultFilter when serving from cache. Without cache they are all pretty much the same at 44ms.

> **IActionFilter** - Avg on localhost from cache 4ms
>   **IResultFilter** - Avg on localhost from cache 8ms

So I'll stick with **OnActionExecuted**